# Access Apache VirtualHost from any computer on LAN?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have wamp setup with quite a few websites setup as virtual hosts like this in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName project1.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/project1/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have these input in the wamp machine's host file and I can access them just fine on that machine.

```
127.0.0.1 project1.local
```

However, when I try to put an entry on my OSX machine as (192.168.1.101 being the internal ip of the wamp machine) it won't pull the page up.

```
192.168.1.101 project1.local
```

Is there something else I need to do to make this work from other machines? Thanks!

Comment: I think this answer can help you [Access virtual host from another machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245242/access-virtual-host-from-another-machine#answer-11342625)

Comment: You just required to add another entry in your WAMP machine host file below the `127.0.0.1 project1.local`. This entry must be same as the entry on your OSX Machine:  `192.168.1.101 project1.local`. Try changing to `<VirtualHost *.80>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.101>` (in addition to 127.0.0.1), or simply use `<VirtualHost *>` to put the VH on all addresses.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I added the IP address like this (for anyone else needing an answer): 

NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.101
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.101>
    ServerName imagelark.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/dev/project1/"
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your virtual host config file

In the below code,
 'Client_IP' is the IP of the machine from where you want to access the directory without using any ip on the address bar, just put severname in the address bar like **'servername/'**.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName servername
   DocumentRoot d:\wamp\www\dir_name                        

    <Directory "d:\wamp\www\dir_name">                             
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from 127.0.0.1 Client_IP
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Then, set same servername that you have used for the virtual host on apache server like,

```
server_ip servername
```

in the client machine c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file.

Comment: If you want to allow all client machines then add **Allow from all** in the config file.